# Extract element and attribute of an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm searching a way to automatically extract every elements and attribute used in an xml file (maybe even put them in a table, that would be great). 
I am currently using Oxygen XML editor, and I think it is quite powerful and able to do that, but I have no idea of what actually I will have to do. 
I know about XSLT, but I need it kind of quickly, and I cannot right now start to learn it (although I will in the next future because it seems great!).

Example of the code in the file:

```
<entity_type Code="1" description="Institution"/>
<Institution_type Code="2" MechanicalCode="C" Description="brief description" />
```

What I want is a list of the elements

```
entity_type
institution_type
```

and a list of the attributes

```
Code
Description
MechanicalCode
```

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: What are you expecting the output to look like? HTML? CSV? Something else? Also it helps to show what you've tried even if it doesn't work.

Comment: This exact question (this wording and requirement exactly) was asked recently, I just can't find it.

Comment: I believe this question was answered here and then the answer was deleted. Not sure why - I thought it was a good one, at least in principle.

Comment: Yeah, it was answered, and I even comment the answer, but I do not know why it was deleted! Btw @Matthew Green I would love a CSV out of it, but also a text file like Elements: 1,2,3 - Attributes: 1,2,3 is going to be fine! Unfortunately I do not have the knowledge to put down some code as an example :\ I would love to, but I can't right now!

Comment: So was there anything wrong with the answer already given (and then deleted)? Or is it just that you didn't write it down?

Comment: It was not working, at least not for me

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Note that your example is missing a root element.

Comment: There was some type of error with Saxon, that I reported in the (now gone) comments (was connected with the written code, sorry but right now I cannot be more helpful). The output anyway was a file without any elements.I know that the example is lacking the root.

Comment: I have posted an answer roughly similar to the one deleted. Would you be good enough to test it and see if it produces the same error? It works for me with Saxon as well as any other processor I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you wanted a list of element names and a list of attributes names used in the source XML document, with each distinct name listed only once. The accepted answer does not provide that.

The following stylesheet is based loosely on the answer previously posted by someone else and subsequently deleted. Unlike that answer, this one uses keys to remove duplicates instead of testing for `preceding::*[name()=$name]` which would fail in case of an ancestor with a similar name - in addition to being slow.

For testing purposes, the output is XML (changing it to CSV or similar should be trivial, though).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elem" match="*" use="name()" />
<xsl:key name="attr" match="@*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<nodes>
    <elements>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="elem"/>
    </elements> 
    <attributes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="attr"/>
    </attributes>
</nodes>    
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="*" mode="elem">
    <xsl:if test="count(. | key('elem', name())[1]) = 1">
        <elem><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></elem>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="elem"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="attr"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" >
    <xsl:if test="count(. | key('attr', name())[1]) = 1">
        <attr><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></attr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Testing with the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root radical="1">
    <alpha red="2">
        <charlie green="3">
            <echo red="4"/>
            <delta blue="4"/>
        </charlie>
        <delta blue="3">
            <alpha red="4"/>
            <root orange="6"/>
            <foxtrot green="5"/>
            <bravo orange="6"/>
        </delta>
    </alpha>
    <bravo blue="2">
        <golf white="3">
            <echo green="4">
                <hotel black="5" red="4"/>
            </echo>
        </golf>
    </bravo>
</root>
```

results in output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodes>
  <elements>
    <elem>root</elem>
    <elem>alpha</elem>
    <elem>charlie</elem>
    <elem>echo</elem>
    <elem>delta</elem>
    <elem>foxtrot</elem>
    <elem>bravo</elem>
    <elem>golf</elem>
    <elem>hotel</elem>
  </elements>
  <attributes>
    <attr>radical</attr>
    <attr>red</attr>
    <attr>green</attr>
    <attr>blue</attr>
    <attr>orange</attr>
    <attr>white</attr>
    <attr>black</attr>
  </attributes>
</nodes>
```

Comment: I tried today, check everything, and yes this one work perfectly, and it was very easy to get a CSV out of it! Thank you very very much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I tried to solve it, JAXP was used to render (transform) the result:

XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <BASE href="hrEf" target="tArgEt"/>
        <SCRIPT type="typE" src="src"/>
        <STYLE type="typE" media="mEdIA"/>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="OnlOAd" onunload="OnUnlOAd" background="bAckgrOUnd"/>
</HTML>
```

XSL template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output
        method="text"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="no"
        media-type="text/plain"
    />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select ="local-name(.)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
            &#160;&#64;<xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>&#61;&#34;<xsl:value-of select="."/>&#34;
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result:

```
HTML
    HEAD
        BASE
             @href="hrEf"

             @target="tArgEt"

        SCRIPT
             @src="src"

             @type="typE"

        STYLE
             @media="mEdIA"

             @type="typE"


    BODY
             @background="bAckgrOUnd"

             @onload="OnlOAd"

             @onunload="OnUnlOAd"
```

Notice how it works regardless the depth of the tree; cheers!

Comment: Glad to be helpful to someone...XD